# Getting href of parent page from child page within the same origin

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am working on a project using Next.js, and I have a scenario where I need to open a new tab from one page to another using the `<Link>` component provided by Next.js. I am using `target="_blank"` in the `<Link>` to open the linked page in a new tab.

Now, once the new tab is opened, I want to access some information or data from the parent page (the page that opened the new tab) within this child page. Specifically, I need to retrieve the href value of the parent page.

I understand that accessing data between different origins raises security concerns and might be restricted due to cross-origin policies, but in my case, both the parent and child pages are from the same origin.

Additionally, I need to implement some logic in the child page for the back button click event. When the user clicks the back button in the child page, I want to check if the href of the opener (parent) page is the same as the href of the child page. If they match, it indicates that the user is navigating back to the same page they came from. In this situation, I would like to close the child tab and switch the focus back to the opener page to avoid duplication of tabs.

I've tried using `window.opener` to access the parent page's window object, but it seems to be null in my case.

Is there any way to achieve this within the same origin? How can I get the href of the parent page from the child page opened in a new tab? Additionally, how can I handle the back button click event to close the child tab and switch focus back to the opener page if the href values match? Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Not sure if I understood it correctly but I assumed you want to access the "source" or "referrer" not the "parent" page since you mentioned "different origins"?